# Javascript alert locks up page on IOS Chrome after using a file input

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome

Is this a problem with Chrome or something that I'm doing wrong? I noticed that if I use a file input element to get the file browser/camera prompt to show, then follow it up with something that would cause an alert message, it locks up the entire page forcing me to kill the app to make things work again. Here's a simple jsfiddle that shows the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/etc4bxpq/

HTML:

```
<input type="file">
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

JS:

```
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', event => {
  alert(1);
});
```

Tap on the file input, then tap on the Click Me button. The alert won't fire and the page will lock up. It seems to only happen with Chrome on IOS. Safari seems to work just fine.

Comment: Have you tried with the old ES5 format?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem to matter. Attempting to trigger the alert locks up the browser

Comment: Uhm, seems like a iOS bug!

Answer (score 1):

Having same error with same conditions. I tried wrapping my alerts and prompts with setTimeout function as suggested by some but it did not work for me, tried putting input in another page and calling it inside iframe, also did not works for me. The only solution works for me is using alert modals instead native javascript alert and prompt function. Also if you open chrome settings menu and close it, script continues it's execution which is very strange.

Comment: So far, modals have also become the solution I have come up with, but I still would like to know why native alerts cause issues (unless it actually is a bug with ios browsers).